# What will be the best method to check the if statement in another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

Basically if view `controller 1` `number == 2` I want activate a method in `view controller 2`. What will be the best method for this. I was thinking of using the `NSUserDefaults` boolean for this.

View controller 1

```
if (number ==2) {  
}
```

View controller 2

```
-(void)numberequals2 {
    NSLog(@"number2")
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by activate? Do you want to call a method if number==2?

Comment: Yes,sorry for the miss communication. But the method needs to be call in view controller 2.

Comment: Then you can just create an object and call the method, but will you please clarify, if I am wrong?

Comment: You'll need some sort of reference to the other view controller in order to do this. Depending on your setup, this might be better implemented with notifications or delegates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (number == 2) { 

     //create an object for ViewController2 if it doesn't exists
     [viewController2Obj numberequals2]
}
```

Comment: My situation is going to be different. Sorry didn't word it right. I will post a new question later.